# Guava Cache Access From Different Classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, guava, spring-cache

Is it possible to access the guava cache from any of the class within that project?

Suppose if I create class cache `bannelUrl` within `FetchBanner.java`, can the values from `bannelUrl` from any other class other than `FetchBanner.java`?

Comment: If the class exposes the cache, sure, why not? If it is private only, then no (unless you are allowing Reflection)

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing of your question is a bit unclear, so if I'm answering the wrong question, please try rephrasing it.

A Guava cache is a Java object like any other Java object. Its visibility can be as narrow or as wide as you want it to be. I would recommend making access to it available through a method (or methods) on the class it's in, rather than directly, since that keeps the pieces of your implementation better encapsulated. But it's totally up to you.